# Scraping data after selecting options in input

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape a data from this site
https://www.marketbeat.com/insider-trades/ceo-share-buys-and-sales/.
Problem is i want to choose some options before scraping

[image]

**In the Country button i want to check every button**

This is default state

[image]

After scraping data i want to repeat this process but with

**Transaction type Sold shares checked**

For now i have
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VUVSI5BGiN5lCFrj4WGfJaZg1-wtU2f1?usp=sharing

If someone could give me some hints i would apprecate that thanks

Comment: If you are wanting to make sure all the items are checked in the dropdown filter, I would look at the parent <ul> item. From there, there should be list of all the contents below. Then you can iterate through a loop of all the <input> tags and make sure you are clicking on all of those.

After that loop, you should be able to easily select the Sold filter with a single .click() on the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. You have to click the labels rather than the checkboxes

```
dropdownButton = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'dropdownCountry');
dropdownButton.click();

dropdownList = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//ul[@aria-labelledby="dropdownCountry"]')
countryButtons = dropdownList.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "label");
countryButtons.pop(0)
for i in countryButtons:
    i.click()

soldSharesButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//option[@value="Sell"]')
soldSharesButton.click()
```